# Partially print report, stopping the printer until more data comes

Tags: .net, printing, printers

I'm not sure I even know how to ask this question properly but here goes nothing.

My boss asked me yesterday to see if it's possible to get the printer to start printing some "partial" data, and stop/pause until there's more data to print.

Let me perhaps try and make this more clear...

We have a device, that's constantly calculating stuff, and sending the data to our DB...  They want for the results to be printed as they come, but in the same page! What she meant by this  was: basically "blocking" the printer, until more data comes, and then resume from there... In the same page, without ever ejecting the page... not until it's full.

As far as I know this is not possible to do with regular printers on standard A4 paper. Not unless we send the instructions directly to the printer as data comes.

After searching the interwebs, (without being 100% sure of what "terms" to search for), and telling my boss that there's no simple way to do it and, we're not going to spend more time investigating this issue... However, for the sake of having some more knowledge on the matter, I decided to ask here hoping someone will enlighten me on this.

Help me StackOverflow. You're my only hope.

PS: Our solution is done with .NET 4.5 and SQL Server.

Comment: Might be some useful things for you here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091/en-us